# Storyboard Static Tableview Cells Not Accessible

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

Using a storyboard, I've created a tableview that contains about 6 static cells that have a variety of labels, switches, and views within where one of them is not visible on startup. This made designing the cells pretty easy. Unfortunately, the plan was to populate and set the switches and things in ALL 6 cells by parsing a data structure. What I've found, and not totally unexpected, was the the invisible last cell is not instantiated when I parse the data structure and so the switches, etc. are not configured.

In a dynamic tableview, I would just take care of some of this in cellForIndexPath, etc. where I could configure the cell before it appears. BUT, with static cells you cannot have that datasource method around or it all won't work.

Any suggestions on how to force instantiation of the the last hidden cell (or all the cells I want) before it is scrolled into view? What are other ways to approach this?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Everything works the same way as with dynamic cells. You can still access cellForRowAtIndexPath. Did you implement the delegate?

Comment: use the tableview delegate and datasource and refer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260160/how-to-set-conditional-static-tableview-cell-content-in-storyboard/36260592#36260592

Answer (score 0):

just need add the `<UITableViewDelegate>` and add the method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Since static cells are only possible in a TableViewController his class should already support the TableViewDelegate.. so no need to add it, just implement the delegate method.

Comment: Actually, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a UITableViewDataSource delegate, but yes that works, but ONLY for visible cells. I wanted to populate invisible cells. I parsed and configured things with a "manager" but this was flawed from the beginning and now I'm refactoring to have the table view do the parsing and using `UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` within the datasource method to parse my data structure and configure the cells. Hope it works ;)