# How to set conditional static tableview cell content in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have made a tableview controller with static cells in my storyboard(I used static cells because its a settings screen where almost all the cells are static except one). There is one cell which takes different contents(from different UITableViewCell xib s) on different conditions. If I try to assign that cell some value in func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath..., then I ve to set the other cells also. Is there a way where I can set only one cell and take the other cells as how they are in the xib.?

Also if at all it is possible can I assign a static cell with contents of a cell's xib in case I already have one made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of implementing **cellForRowAtIndexPath** for **UITableViewController** with static cells. You only need to make **IBOutlet** of your cell labels or the controls whose value you want to change at runtime on conditional bases. After that in UITableViewController class viewDidLoad or ViewDidAppear change the required control values based on your conditions.

Comment: I don't want to edit a label. I want to change the entire cell. I have 2 xibs and on certain condition i want to use one and the other one otherwise. So how to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

use willdisplaycell function

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      if (indexPath.row == 5){ //your row where you want to change


      }

    }
```

other row will be as it is in stroybord

Comment: I want to load different nib files for the cell on different conditions. It doesn't happen in this method. And in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, all the cells change and the static cells that I made in the storyboard are replaced by the default cells. How to change only selected cells and let the remaining as they are

Comment: use different cell identifiers  for each cells and subclass that cell

Comment: or the other option is making @IBOulets as mentioned by - waris-shams